# Reputation changes listed twice

Tags: bug, reputation

Briefly the up- and downvotes on my last question where shown twice (see image). Is that as it should be?

[image]

It has happened again twice:

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: Briefly? So it's not reproducible now? If so probably some glitch in AJAX updating.

Comment: @RobertLongson See my edit.